# /api/sitecore is not working in CD server

Tags: webapi

Sitecore Version: 9.0.2

Environment: Azure PaaS CD

We are trying to call `/api/sitecore/controller/actionname` with AJAX. It's working on the CM server but not on the CD server.

I disabled custom errors and removed HTTP error configuration in web.config, but it still redirects to the custom 404 page I've created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was moved to SPEAK routes in Sitecore 9 and unavailable on CD server. You can resolve it by adding this snippet to your routing configuration (if you really need this API route - best practice is to create your own routes for your API calls):

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["role:define"] == "ContentDelivery")
{
   RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Sitecore.Speak.Commands", "api/sitecore/{controller}/{action}");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `/sitecore/api` route is a default route added by Sitecore in configs that are specific to the content management aspects of the platform. These configs are not enabled for content delivery. As noted in [x3mxray's answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/19717/342), they can be reenabled, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead of reenabling the default routes for other functionality you (probably) don't need on your CD servers, I would recommend mapping a custom route to your method and not relying on the `/api/sitecore` prefix.

## 1. Create pipeline processor to register route

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;

public class RegisterWebApiRoutes
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomApiRoute",
                                   "api/customaction",
                                   new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" },
                                   new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
        );
    }
}
```

## 2. Create patch config to patch in your pipeline processor

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore role:require="Standalone OR ContentManagement OR ContentDelivery">
        <pipelines>
            <initialize>
                <processor type="Custom.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterWebApiRoutes,Custom" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
            </initialize>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

## 3. Update your code to reference this new route

Don't forget to update your code to use the new route!

Comment: your answer is reasonable and obvious. but question is not how to implement your cusom route, question is why "/api/sitecore is not working in CD server"

Comment: In my opinion, both answers are missing the mark. This answer is more accurate because it offers a path forward that is more of a best practice and explained well. While @x3mxray's answer is short and answers the immediate question, it offers a hack that shouldn't actually be done. That is why I upvoted this answer.

Comment: @x3mxray - I added a blurb at the beginning of my answer to hopefully more directly answer the question.

Comment: @petenavarra - I added a blurb at the beginning of my answer to hopefully more directly answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue on a project which had a custom pipeline for 404 redirects. Can you look for a similar code in your .config files from CD server?

```
<pipelines>
  <httpRequestBegin>
      <processor type="MyCustomDLL.NotFoundHttpRequestProcessor, MyCustomDLL"
                        patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']">
      </processor>
  </httpRequestBegin>
</pipelines>
```

404 response is hard-coded on the pipeline:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "404 File Not Found";
```

If that is your case, a possible solution would be checking which URL is being requested in your custom pipeline. 
e.g.:

```
if (args.RequestUrl.LocalPath.StartsWith("/api/sitecore", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    return;
}
```