# Sitecore api call giving 404 on ajax post call on CD server

Tags: sitecore-api

I am using sitecore 9.0 with SXA 1.8.1
I am trying to call a server side method using ajax call.
The controller inherits `ServicesApiController`. 
The ajax `Get` method is works fine on CD server. But the post method is give 404 error

Below is the controller code

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [Route("api/service/sitename/methodname1")]
        public string methodname1()
        {
            try { 
            //some code
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

                return string.Empty;

            }
        }
```

ajax get call for above method. It works fine for both CM and CD server

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/service/sitename/methodname1",
        type: "GET",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (data) {
        console.log("error", data);
        }
    });
```

Server side post method

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 [Route("api/service/sitename/method2")]
 public string method2(string Query)
 {
    try
    {
        //some code
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objResults);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {      
     return null;
    }
  }
```

ajax post call for the above method. This gives 404 error cd server but works fine in CM

```
$.ajax({  
           type: 'POST',  
           dataType: 'json',  
           url: '/api/service/sitename/method2',  
           data: { Query: query},  
           beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loadingImage').removeClass("hide");
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loadingImage').addClass("hide");
            },
           success: function (searchData) {  

               },  
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  

           }  
       });
```

is there anything missing ?

Comment: try this link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19716/api-sitecore-is-not-working-in-cd-server

Comment: Instead of using api/sitecore  default router you need to create a pipeline processor to register your own route , yes the above mentioned link is the correct answer .

Comment: the ajax GET method call worked without any routing configuration. Not sure why its not working for POST method